# Rails - Heroku deploy issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gcc

I am trying again to deploy my app to HEROKU, but i get the following error logs. I tried multiple time to redo the whole process as indicated on Heroku website. The app works perfectly locally. It looks like a GCC problem, but I am not sure. Can someone understand what this is saying please?

```
2018-11-27T00:49:20.117600+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-11-27T00:49:34.778024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 19111 -e production`
2018-11-27T00:49:40.281594+00:00 app[web.1]: warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby25, which recognizes
2018-11-27T00:49:40.281619+00:00 app[web.1]: warning: 2.5.3-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.5.0.
2018-11-27T00:49:40.281623+00:00 app[web.1]: warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
2018-11-27T00:49:42.419459+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: gcc: not found
2018-11-27T00:49:42.420819+00:00 app[web.1]: COMPILATION ERROR: error executing "gcc -shared  -Wl,--compress-debug-sections=zlib -fPIC -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wmisleading-indentation -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wduplicated-cond -Wrestrict -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -I /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-linux -I /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/include -L/app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib -o \"/app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.5.0/Inline_String_9a6686966a50705d94442f198bc2c408.so\" \"/app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.5.0/Inline_String_9a6686966a50705d94442f198bc2c408.c\"  ": pid 8 exit 127
2018-11-27T00:49:42.420823+00:00 app[web.1]: Renamed /app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.5.0/Inline_String_9a6686966a50705d94442f198bc2c408.c to /app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.5.0/Inline_String_9a6686966a50705d94442f198bc2c408.c.bad
2018-11-27T00:49:42.430319+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: gcc: not found
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329381+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329383+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329385+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329387+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329391+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329393+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329395+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329399+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329400+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329402+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `each'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329406+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329409+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329413+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329417+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329418+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329422+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329426+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329429+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329433+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329435+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329438+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329442+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329446+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329449+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329452+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329456+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329459+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329462+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329465+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329467+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329471+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `new'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329474+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `<main>'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329478+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329481+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329483+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329487+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329490+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329494+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329497+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329501+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329504+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329506+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329509+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329513+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329516+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329520+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329522+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329526+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329529+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329532+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329534+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.329538+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2018-11-27T00:49:47.340413+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-11-27T00:49:47.340417+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.6 application starting in production
2018-11-27T00:49:47.340446+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-11-27T00:49:47.340448+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-11-27T00:49:47.454055+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-11-27T00:49:47.436377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: How did you deploy? By the cli or in the site?

Comment: Hey @MateusLuiz, I deployed using the CLI. using :
`$ git add .`
`$ git commit -am "make it better"`
`$ git push heroku master` I worked for 7 months on this website, and now it is about time to get it going, but this issue has blocked me for 2 weeks. Impossible to find the solution on search engines.

Comment: @MateusLuiz what do you think ?

Comment: Looks normal to me, can you try to deploy via heroku dashboard? In the site

Comment: Also, try to connect through ssh in the server and try to update the gcc

Comment: $ bundle show --paths | ruby -e "STDIN.each_line {|dep| puts dep.split('/').last if File.directory?(File.join(dep.chomp, 'ext')) }"
bcrypt-3.1.11
bindex-0.5.0
byebug-10.0.2
concurrent-ruby-1.1.3
eventmachine-1.2.7
ffi-1.9.25
hiredis-0.6.3
nio4r-2.3.1
nokogiri-1.8.5
nokogumbo-2.0.1
pg-0.18.1
puma-3.12.0
rb-fsevent-0.10.3
recommendify-ruby-0.3.8
scrypt-3.0.6
sqlite3-1.3.13
thin-1.7.2
thread_safe-0.3.6
unf_ext-0.0.7.5
websocket-driver-0.6.5